# How to convert VOB files to a single AVI file

Tags: conversion, avi, vob

I want to convert a DVD which has many VOB files into a single playable AVI file on my computer.

I can convert each individual VOB file to an AVI but is there some way to convert all of them into a single AVI file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

I used the free [Format Factory](http://www.pcfreetime.com) which works very nicely.

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net) looks interesting and is also free whilst MS Expression Encoder is not free. Note that in 2024, [Microsoft Expression](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-expression-encoder-replacement-for/32d4e460-8239-49b9-b013-d2668770276b) is no longer in development or supported.

Answer (score 3):

### You can do this all via command line using `cat` and FFmpeg.

Unclear what OS you are on, but if you are using a Unix-like system — such as macOS or Linux — you have more options at your disposal; most all of them 100% free!

As per [this answer for a similar question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/804182), you can use `cat` to concatenate the separate VOB files into one VOB file like this:

```
cat VTS_01_*.vob > output.vob
```

Then with that `output.vob` you can run a command like this; a fairly common FFmpeg command that will copy video streams without transcoding:

```
ffmpeg -i output.vob -codec copy output.avi
```

If that somehow doesn’t suit your needs, or you want to convert the video and audio to another format, then just read up on how to use FFmpeg and set command like options and just always use `ffmpeg -I output.vob` for your input.

Answer (score 0):

## Try [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net).

When you open the first VOB, it asks you if you want to combine it with the others available. Therefore the VOBs have to be in the same folder.

After that you can export the whole thing to AVI.

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner $(printf -- "-i %s " VTS_01_*.VOB) -c:v libx265 -x265-params "lossless=1:no-deblock=1:no-sao=1" -map_metadata -1 "../MOVIE.mkv"
```

where `$(printf -- "-i %s " VTS_01_*.VOB)` creates the list of files to combine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1152820)

Comment: @music2myear: I didn't critic anyone and this DOES answer the question.. I used MKV as an example.. you can use AVI or any other format that ffmpeg supports (a ton).

Comment: "for example" only comes if you've provided some explanation. I think English is probably not your first language, which is just fine, but the word "critique" does not mean "criticize". A line of code is not answer. Please give an explanation to accompany your line of code and then you'll have an answer, and not just a comment.

Comment: @music2myear I assumed people here know how to code, at least a little. anyway to accomodate your ignorance, I edited the answer.

Comment: @music2myear you should have just tried ``printf -- "-i %s " VTS_01_*.VOB`` in the directory where the VOB files are, to see "the magic" :P

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions proposed in the other answers won't work with encrypted DVDs, and almost all the commercial DVDs are encrypted. They are easy to decrypt, but you need a tool that will do that.

MakeMKV will do do it for free (it's a paid software for BluRay decrypting, but free for DVDs). It can read a DVD, a DVD image, or a VIDEO_TS folder that contains the VOB files, and produces a MKV file without reencoding (I assume today that an AVI file is no longer desired).

If reencoding is desired, then Handrake is a must-have software, which will decrypt and reencode any DVD (it won't decrypt BluRays, though).

Answer (score -1):

... or if you are using Windows, you can do VOB to AVI conversions using [Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/EncoderPro_Overview.aspx).

Haven't tried combining AVI files, but you should be able to by dragging them to the Timeline, and encoding as an AVI

Answer (score -1):

If you're willing to pay the 20 bucks, [DIVX PRO](http://www.divx.com/) has a great high quality (up to 1080p) conversion software of multiple video file types, including VOB files.